# Send geolocation data to the server to another html

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

ok so guys I am building an app using cordova its a 2way app i.e the first app which contain its current location and i want to store its latitude and longitude to a server then in 2nd app uses 1st app location data as a marker location and sorry guys but i don't have any functional knowledge of php so am i be able to make this using node.js? and if yes then can you tell me some useful resource for node.js which might help me to accomplish this task? I am fairly new to back-end programming so any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance....

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#geolocation.getCurrentPosition may help. Once you get latitude and longitude you can send them with xmlhttprequest using GET

Comment: Thanks for reply i know that i have to first use post method of xhr and in the peremeter i have to use the json obj for lat an lon so i have 2 questuons 
1st im i be able to send 2var in instead of json(just for knowledge )
And my main question is that how to recive data from that php?
I know that i have to use the response text stuff  but the problem is that it only react with an event but i want to make like whenever the location of app 1 is fetched it will use that infor for plotting new marker so... Please help me if you can....